# option clash for package natbib

Tags: errors, natbib

as I use the command: `\usepackage [square]{natbib}`, I get the following error:

```
Option clash for package natbib.
```

How I can solve this problem.

Comment: that means you have loaded natbib twice with different options., don't do that, just load it once.

Comment: HI and welcome, package `natbib` has been loaded before with different options. Maybe in some thesis or journal class.

Comment: I use the elsarticle.cls and need cite my references in brackets. but natbib default is parentheses. How I can use brackets without changing the natbib options?

Comment: I think you may want: `\documentclass[square]{elsarticle}`. Hard to say for sure since you have not given a complete document to work with....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jon : that is a good idea. I faced the similar issue when trying to use `\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}` with a custom document class `risa` which uses `natbib.sty`. As you suggested, `\documentclass[sort&compress]{risa}` solved the problem.